# trouble using e.parameter in a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a script that is published as a service for a web app and i'm trying to build search functionality in it. the scipt is intended to allow the user to enter a term in a text box called **searchBox**, click search and show the row(s) of a spreadsheet containing that term.

```
function searchClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var searchResultPanel = app.getElementById('searchResultPanel');
  var searchResultPane = app.getElementById('searchResultPane');
  var searchCloseButton = app.getElementById('searchCloseButton');
  var searchTerm = e.parameter.searchBox;
  if (searchTerm.toString().length == 6) {
    var searchList = ArrayLib.filterByText(dataValues, 1, searchTerm.toString());
    var searchTrim = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < searchList.length; i++) {
      var searchTrim1 = searchList[i].slice(1, 6);
      var searchTrim2 = searchList[i].slice(8, 10);
      var searchTrim3 = searchList[i].slice(17, 19);
      searchTrim.push(searchTrim1.concat(searchTrim2,searchTrim3));
    }
  }
```

there are a few other else if's below that and then the handler should show the results but **e.parameter.searchBox** is coming back undefined. if i manually set **searchTerm** the script runs fine.

i am using **e.parameter** successfully in another handler in the same script so i am at a loss on this one.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show is not really relevant to help... did you give a name to the "searchBox" when you created it or is it its ID ?

The e.parameter uses the **name** of the widget as reference.

EDIT (following comments): in the GUI builder try to add every callbackElement by their names (for widgets or ID for panels) separated by commas like this :

[image]

Comment: the ID of widget is searchBoxMain and the Name is searchBox. line 6 in the code above is the only place i am using e.parameter so included it for reference. i get a **TypeError: Cannot call method "toString()" of undefined** when it runs.

Comment: are you sure there is not a typo in the name ? You could try `Logger.log(e.parameter.source)` to see what it returns

Comment: i just shortened the name to sb in order to eliminate typos and it's still coming up undefined. aslo, i have a short test handler that is using e.parameter.custID with the same problem, however, e.parameter.custID is working properly in a 3rd handler. these are all connected to a gui created in the gui builder.

Comment: did you try the logger I suggested ? the gui builder is sometimes tricky when dealing with callbackelements. Is the widget a child of your main callbackelement or did you add every elements separately ?

Comment: Logger.log(e.parameter.source) gives me searchButtonMain which is the buttion connected to the handler.

Comment: the gui has a textBox (name:searchBox) and a button (ID:searchButtonMain) on a flowPanel which is on another flowPanel which is also on a larger flowPanel which is a child of the component.

Comment: actually it would be component1 -> flowPanel (ID:custMainContainer) -> flowPanel (ID:custAddSearchPanel) -> textBox (name:searchBox) and button (ID:searchButtonMain).

Comment: I just tested a few UI build with GUI builder and everything runs fine... maybe you could share the spreadsheet with me ? my mail is on my profile.

Comment: i'd love to share it with you but it's not spreadsheet script (it just references the spreadsheet) it's running as a service and i don't see how to share it with you. also where on your profile is your mail?

Comment: sorry, my mistake... try Logger.log(e.parameter) to show the callbackelements 's content. (not source :-)

Comment: my email is not visible ? weird ! I don't see any pref to hide it... I see it... I'll have to check that. anyway, did you try the new log ?

Comment: Serge, sorry i had to leave here is what shows on the e.parameter log:  `{clientY=122, clientX=1559, eventType=click, ctrl=false, meta=false, source=searchButtonMain, button=1, alt=false, screenY=207, screenX=1559, y=38, shift=false, x=34}`

Comment: Your searchBox is indeed missing, it should go like this for example `{clientY=82, clientX=132, NameBox=Name, eventType=click, ctrl=false, meta=false, source=Button1, button=1, alt=false, screenY=546, screenX=789, y=18, shift=false, x=101}` your callback element should be there, try to put it directly from the code.

Comment: that was it! i coded into my `doGet()` and it worked - strange. thanks so much for your help.

Comment: also added the callback element in the GUI builder and that worked too. seems i have a lot left to learn. thanks again.